# Discrete random variable with infinite expectation

Tags: probability, random-variables

> Consider a discrete random variable taking only positive integers as values with 
>   $$\mathbb{P}[X=n]=\frac{1}{n(n+1)}.$$
>   (a) Show that $\mathbb{E}[X]=\infty$.
>
> (b) Show that $\mathbb{P}[X \geq n]= \frac{1}{n}$.
>   What does this imply for Markov's inequality ?

Comment: Dear Albanian Eagle, is this homework? What have you tried?

Comment: @Albanian_EAGLE How would you define $E[Y]$ for a general integer valued random variable $Y$?

Comment: I have solved this question but I found it interesting that why I posted here so people could see and discuss :)

Comment: It would have been more profitable to add a discussion of the problem rather than to flatly post its statement, contrary to the advice given on how to ask questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(a)** $$E(X)=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}x \cdot P[X=x]\\=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}x \cdot\dfrac{1}{x(x+1)}\\ =\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x+1}.$$ Clearly this is divergent. So, we have $E(X)=\infty.$

**(b)** Note that $$P[X=n]=\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)}=\dfrac{1}{n}-\dfrac{1}{n+1}$$ and  $$P[X\le n-1]=\sum_{x=1}^{n-1}\left[\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{x+1}\right]=1-\dfrac{1}{n}.$$Clearly we get $$P[X\ge n]=1-P[X\le n-1]=\dfrac{1}{n}.$$
Here markov's inequality gives $$P[X\ge n]\le \dfrac{E[X]}{n}=\infty$$